# What is methodology behind retrieving k most relevant articles using Wikipedia Python library?

Tags: python, wikipedia, information-retrieval

Does the Wikipedia python library automatically retrieve the most relevant k documents based on given query? What is the underlying structure of retrieving those documents? Does it use TF-IDF or any other approach?

Comment: Which Python library for Wikipedia do you mean?

Comment: [This one?](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: yes , Wikipedia python api : https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [the module's source code](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py), `wikipedia` queries the Wikipedia API and returns its results. The order of documents returned is therefore determined by Wikipedia's own *CirrusSearch*, which is built on Elasticsearch. You can find more information [in the Wikipedia API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search_and_discovery).